# error: pathspec "mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, git-clone

репу клонировал так

```
git clone <урлрепы> -b mybranch
```

сейчас вот хочу обновить текущий код из репы, для начала переключаюсь на ветку

```
git checkout mybranch
```

на что получаю **error: pathspec "mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.**
не создавать же мне ветку еще раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если всё обстоит именно так, как описано, то вероятнее всего нужно перейти (с помощью команды cd) в тот каталог, куда был склонирован репозиторий:

```
# репозиторий клонируется в папку repo-name
git clone https://github.com/name/repo-name.git

# переходим в неё
cd repo-name

# теперь git должен обнаружить репозиторий
git status
```